# Catching the Page Number of a Pager Being Clicked

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

It is possible to add an onClientLoad eventHandler to a viewPanel:

https://xcellerant.net/2013/01/14/viewpanel_onclientload

Clicking a Pager results in the onClientLoad being fired.

Question: is it possible to catch the Page Number of the Pager being clicked?

Comment: Why would you want/need the specific "page number" of the Pager?

Comment: In order to synchronize what is displayed in an iframe in a navigation solution. We have 10 articles per Page, when clicking e.g. Page 3, the top article (number 21) should then be activated and displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an on click event to every page number within pager in XPage's onClientLoad CSJS code.
Use dojo.query to get all a-tags within pager:

```js
    dojo.query('[id$=pagerWithClickEvents] a').forEach(function(entry) {
        entry.addEventListener("click", function() {
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        });
    });
```

[image]

This XPage is a working example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:viewPanel
        rows="3"
        value="#{view1}"
        id="viewPanel1">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:pager
                partialRefresh="true"
                layout="Previous Group Next"
                xp:key="headerPager"
                id="pagerWithClickEvents">
            </xp:pager>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView
                var="view1"
                databaseName="names.nsf"
                viewName="People">
            </xp:dominoView>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xp:viewColumn
            columnName="$17"
            id="viewColumn1">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader
                value="Name"
                id="viewColumnHeader1">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
        <xp:viewColumn
            columnName="$16"
            id="viewColumn4">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader
                value="E-Mail"
                id="viewColumnHeader4">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onClientLoad"
            submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            dojo.query('[id$=pagerWithClickEvents] a').forEach(function(entry) {
                entry.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    alert(this.innerHTML);
                });
            });
        ]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:viewPanel>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works fine. However, I had to add the dojo.query inside viewPanel as an onClientLoad eventHandler, otherwise it only fired at the first click, not on subsequent clicks. My next step is now to trigger SSJS from this CSJS.

Comment: Oh thank you, this was the part I missed :) - I updated my example XPage. It works for pager inside view panel now too.